# Configuring multiple versions of Grunt cache-bust for DEV and PROD

Tags: javascript, caching, gruntjs, browser-cache

I have an Angular Boilerplate project, which has two configurations: BUILD (Dev mode) and COMPILE(Production code). I'm trying to configure **cacheBust** to work differently depending on what kind of build I am generating. Here is my current code:

```
 cacheBust: {
  compile: {
    options: {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    algorithm: 'md5',
    length: 16,
    deleteOriginals: true
  },
  assets: {
    files: [{
        src: ['<%= compile_dir %>/index.html']
      }]
    }
  },
  build: {
    options: {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    algorithm: 'md5',
    length: 16,
    deleteOriginals: true
  },
  assets: {
    files: [{
        src: ['<%= build_dir %>/index.html']
      }]
    }
  }
```

}

And in my `build` and `compile` tasks I'm calling this like so:

```
 grunt.registerTask( 'build', [
    'clean', 'html2js', 'jshint', 'coffeelint', 'coffee',
    'concat:build_css', 'copy:build_app_assets', 'copy:build_vendor_assets',
    'copy:build_appjs', 'copy:build_vendorjs', /*'copy:build_app_admin',*/ 'index:build', 'cacheBust:b','karmaconfig',
    'karma:continuous' 
  ]);

grunt.registerTask( 'compile', [
    'copy:compile_assets', /*'copy:compile_assets_admin',*/'concat:compile_js', 'ngAnnotate','uglify', 'index:compile','cacheBust:a'
  ]);
```

This doesn't seem to be triggering the correct mechanism. While the task is getting called, and executed without errors, I don't see any cache busting happening, and don't see any log messages that I normally see.

What am I doing wrong?